# Page reloads again and again after authenciated keycloak

Tags: keycloak, react-hooks

I follow these steps (https://scalac.io/user-authentication-keycloak-1/)
to authenciate my react app with keycloak. But one small different thing  here is that I am using react hook to manage my state(the code below). That causes the page reload again and again. Do you have any idea?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import UserInfo from "./UserInfo";
import Logout from "./Logout";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

// The difference is here
function Secured(props) {
  const [keycloak, setKeycloak] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenciated, setAuthenciation] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const keycloak = Keycloak("/keycloak.json");
    keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" }).then(authenticated => {
      setKeycloak(keycloak);
      setAuthenciation(authenticated);
    });
  });

  if (keycloak) {
    if (isAuthenciated)
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
            This is a Keycloak-secured component of your application. You
            shouldn't be able to see this unless you've authenticated with
            Keycloak.
          </p>
          <UserInfo keycloak={this.state.keycloak} />
          <Logout keycloak={this.state.keycloak} />
        </div>
      );
    else return <div>Unable to authenticate!</div>;
  }
  return <div>Initializing Keycloak...</div>;
}

export default Secured;
```

Comment: I think you are missing `useEffect` second parameter: `useEffect(()=>{/*...*/},[])` to only run once.

Comment: Glad it worked! Ill add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to include the dependencies of `useEffect`. Not setting them makes `useEffect` to run on every render. In case you only want it to run once we set the dependencies as an empty array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const keycloak = Keycloak("/keycloak.json");
    keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" }).then(authenticated => {
        setKeycloak(keycloak);
        setAuthenciation(authenticated);
    });
}, []);
```